# Задача про Сортировку дробей. В коде есть какая-то ошибка, но я не понимаю какая. Пожалуйста подскажите

Tags: python

```
count = int(input())

ls = []
for _ in range(count):
    line = input()
    ls.append(list(map(int, line.split('/'))))

ls.sort(key=lambda x: x[0]/x[1])

for i1, i2 in ls:
    print('%d/%d' % (i1, i2))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А что там думать. Задайте две дроби 3/6 и 1/2 и посмотрите, что вы получите. И соответствует-ли ваш результат условию (Если в списке есть две равные дроби то....)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

можно еще попробовать модуль [fractions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html), примерно так:

```
from fractions import Fraction

fr = ['1/2','2/3','3/7','1/10']
ls = sorted(fr, key=lambda x: Fraction(*map(int,x.split('/'))))

print(*ls, sep='\n')
'''
1/10
3/7
1/2
2/3
```

Comment: точнооооо, я совсем забыл про этот модуль, спасибо вам за ответ

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы добавить второе условие достаточно переделать лямбду `lambda x: (x[0] / x[1], x[0])`. Питон сравнивает кортежи слева направо. Если первые элементы разные, они определят порядок, иначе порядок определят вторые элементы. Вот и всё...

... но есть маленький шанс что этого мало.

Ясно что

> ```
>   n     n + 1
> ----- > -----
> n - 1     n
> ```

потому что n<sup>2</sup> > (n - 1)(n + 1) = n<sup>2</sup> - 1.

Но вот пример:

> ```
> $ python
> ...
> @>>> n = 91566432
> @>>> n / (n - 1) > (n + 1) / n
> False
> @>>> n * n > (n + 1) * (n - 1)
> True
> ```

Неравенство с делениями вычисляется с ошибкой. Операция `/` в Питоне возвращает вещественное число конечной точности. Тут точности не хватает. Неравенство с умножениями всегда вычисляется правильно - Питон умножает целые числа точно. Чтобы сравнивать дроби через умножения потребуется написать процедуру сравнения руками:

```
import functools


def cmp_(f1, f2):
    n1, d1 = f1
    n2, d2 = f2
    diff = n1 * d2 - n2 * d1
    if diff != 0:
        return diff
    return n1 - n2


fractions = [tuple(map(int, input().split('/'))) for _ in range(int(input()))]
fractions.sort(key=functools.cmp_to_key(cmp_))
for n, d in fractions:
    print(f'{n}/{d}')
```

Comment: ответ вроде как рабочий, но пройдено 0 из 11 тестов, если у вас получится исправить код, пожалуйста напишите

Comment: Какая версия Питона?

Comment: Исправленная лямбда сколько тестов проходит?

Comment: а нужно отдельно лямбду здать?

Comment: вот последний код работает на 0 тестов

Comment: работаю я в wing

Comment: Вам все объяснили, разжевали и даже расписали. Показали пример кода. А сами-то вы что за прошедшее время сделали? Покажите ваш (именно ваш, а не уважаемого  Stanislav Volodarskiy) последний код и результат теста, который он не проходит.

Comment: и ещё у меня на пк есть версии: 3.7 и 3.10 питона

Comment: код прикрепил, и он прошёл на 6 из 11 тестов

Comment: В вашем коде замените, пожалуйста, вашу лямбду на лямбду из моего ответа и напишите сколько тестов проходит новый код.

Comment: Для моего последнего кода пришлите описание ошибки любого не работающего теста.

Comment: извините пожалуйста, но я не знаю по каким тестам проверяет программа

Comment: пишет, что ноль тестов пройдено или я простонеправильно поставил